# parenthesis outside a array in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
function [ result ] = addprimes( s, e )
    z = s:e;
    result = sum(z(isprime(z)));
end
```

1. `z= s:e` creates a unit-spaced vector `z` with elements `[s,s+1,s+2,...,e]`
2. `isprime(z)` returns an array with logical `0` or `1` in places depending upon whether it is non-prime or prime.
3. what happens in `z(...)`? What is the name of this operation? can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 3):

This is called logical indexing. An example with some numbers:

```
>> x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
>> isprime(x)
ans =
  1×6 logical array
   0   1   1   0   1   0
>> x(isprime(x))
ans =
     2     3     5
>> sum(x(isprime(x)))
ans =
    10
```

For more details, look at [Logical Indexing – Multiple Conditions](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) and "Logical Indexing" of [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).